# how to call a function that is inside another function in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to call a function that is inside another function and I need it to be called by another external function

I needed to call the funcSon function by the callSon function in the same way that it is in my code, I just can't put the necessary code to call it

My Code

```
export function callSon() { 
   //...space to call the funcSon function
}

export function funcDaddy() {
   function funcSon() {
       console.log('Hello');
   }
   return <View></View>;
}
```

Comment: Are they components. Is `CallDaddy` being called as a component inside `CallSon`

Comment: `funcSon` doesn't exist outside of `funcDaddy`. Why is it defined there? Why does `callSon` need to call `funcSon`? Which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: come on, I developed a music player and it has the main function that encompasses the entire structure of the player and within that function that encompasses everything has the function that only gives play, and I needed to call the play function in another external function, basically how I made this little code to simplify. In the case funcDaddy is the Player that encompasses everything and funcSon is only the play function and callSon is the external function that I need to activate only play when called

Comment: continuing ... In other words, I only need to call the play function (funcSon) in another .js file, so I needed it to be called by an external function (callSon) but unfortunately I don't have the knowledge to be able to call this function):

Answer (score 1):

You can move the state and `funcSon()` logic to a redux store. In that way they will become globally accessible. `redux` and `redux-thunk` must be the ways to go https://react-redux.js.org/. Or you create a custom hook to handle that specific part https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html and reuse it whereever needed.